# Can someone help me with this inexact differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve this equation by converting into an exact differential equation but I couldn't reach the end.so pls help.
I couldn't provide the image because I haven't enough reputation so I am sharing this link so that you can view my attempt and the question.

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s648/sh/29545fe5-ba2b-4d5e-ac46-fd1bc6d8046f/a409f0ea6175b1ae46afbc2b376c5166

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see how to write equations!

Answer (score 0):

If you let $x=u+1$ and $y=v-5$, then the equation becomes

$$(u+v)\; du +(-u+v) \; dv = 0$$

which is homogeneous.

Comment: I know that the equation is homogeneous but what to do next where I left?